# Spring Boot application stuck at: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I am upgrading a Spring Boot application from version 1.5.6 to 2.1.1. When I start the application, it gets stuck at this line:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

When I hit this URL: http://localhost:8888/actuator/health, I get `{"status":"UP"}`

Also when I hit this URL: http://localhost:8888/swagger-ui.html, I see the Swagger UI.

But my main application doesn’t start. Any idea why it’s stuck?

Comment: You should be able to see from your spring loggers where it’s stuck

Comment: Why do you think it's stuck? Put another way, what are you expecting to happen that has not happened?

Comment: There's no message after that. Shouldn't I see a message saying 'Server started'?

Comment: @mhasan - You mean enable DEBUG? Hmm.... how do I do that?

Comment: Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: Interestingly, it IS starting but it's not recognizing 'server.context-path' value which is set to: /api/v2.0. Also, I don't see the 'standard' message saying that it's up & running. Thoughts?

Comment: server.context-path is changed to 'server.servlet.context-path'

Answer (score 1):

You have just to exclude security auto configuration.

Just add on your main SpringbootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Below code was already a part of my application's main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

I could not see any logs saying that application has started or anything as such. I had logging level to DEBUG.

```
 logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    org:
      springframework: DEBUG
```

But when I tried hitting my APIs from localhost, it could get expected response. The application was running on port 8080 in my case.

Comment: Just edited the answer. Logging level was set to DEBUG although I had mentioned here as ERROR. Corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old.

I was stuck similarly when I tried to move from SpringBoot 1.5 to 2.
What fixed it for me was when I added
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })`
based on [differences in springboot2](https://www.baeldung.com/new-spring-boot-2) and [this springboo2 security tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration) . [Spring 2 migration guide -> 2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)